# jQuery clone select list remove selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that is cloning an element on the page each time the user clicks it. It is duplicating a select list for them to choose another option.

However, its cloning the whole element including the option that was selected so all of the new ones appended have a default value which I dont want.

```
 globalLocales = $("<div />").append($('[name=localeID]:first').clone()).html();
 $('select').select2();
```

Is there a way I can remove the selected option during the cloning process so it doesn't carry over to the new element?

I tried using `.removeProp('selected')` in the append as well as `.prop('selected',false);` but that didn't work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to fix the proble is to select a nonexistent value:

```
$("<div />").append($('[name=localeID]:first').clone().val(-1)).html();
```

Or you can find selected option and remove `selected` attribute:

```
$("<div />").append($('[name=localeID]:first').clone()
                    .find(':selected').removeAttr('selected').end()).html();
```

but this is a little clumsy.

Comment: First option worked for me, didnt even think about doing it that way :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can remove the selected attribute with this code.

```
$('[name=localeID] option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
```

Comment: I only want to apply this to the cloned elements, not the existing ones

Comment: Then replace the first part of the selector with your new element.